# Error `window not defined` in Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I know `window` doesn't exist in Node.js, but I'm using React and the same code on both client and server. Any method I use to check if `window` exists nets me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined

How do I get around the fact that I can't do `window && window.scroll(0, 0)`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sawtaytoes has got it. I would run whatever code you have in componentDidMount() and surround it with:

```
if (typeof(window) !== 'undefined') {
  // code here
}
```

If the window object is still not being created by the time React renders the component, you can always run your code a fraction of a second after the component renders (and the window object has definitely been created by then) so the user can't tell the difference.

```
if (typeof(window) !== 'undefined') {
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // code here
    }, 200);
}
```

I would advise against putting state in the setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Placing the `window.` in `componentDidMount` fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 6):

This will settle that issue for you:

```js
typeof(window) === 'undefined'
```

Even if a variable isn't defined, you can use `typeof()` to check for it.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of code shouldn't even be running on the server, it should be inside some `componentDidMount` ([see doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)) hook, which is only invoke client side. This is because it doesn't make sense to scroll the window server side.

However, if you have to reference to window in a part of your code that really runs both client and server, use `global` instead (which represents the global scope - e.g. `window` on the client).

Comment: In one instance, I needed to do `new Audio()`, and I need to check if `window` and `window.Audio` exists. Sadly, if I do it in componentDidMount(), it comes up as undefined in the props of the child module I put it in even if I do it `onClick`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little older but for ES6 style react component classes you can use this class decorator I created as a drop in solution for defining components that should only render on the client side. I like it better than dropping window checks in everywhere.

```
import { clientOnly } from 'client-component';

@clientOnly
class ComponentThatAccessesWindowThatIsNotSafeForServerRendering extends Component {
    render() {
        const currentLocation = window.location;
        return (
            <div>{currentLocation}</div>
        )
    };
}
```

https://github.com/peterlazzarino/client-component

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history= {browserHistory}>
```

if you need to open new page on top in React JS app, use this code in router.js

Comment: Just dropping a piece of code is rarely helpful. Please add an explanation.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `window` and related code to the `mounted()` lifecycle hook. This is because `mounted()` hook is called on the client side only and `window` is available there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some context to your answer. What lifecycle hook and why?