# Window is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJS in my project and I would like to access my current URL like by using window.location.href. When I use window.location.href I get an error saying window is not defined.

```
// --- REACT + CUSTOM-TAGS ---
const SampleApp = ({value}) => {
    // --- CUSTOM-SCRIPTS ---
    addMeta([
        {type: 'meta', content: {content: 'something'}},
        {type: 'link', content: {rel: 'http://link'}},
    ]);

    //Append the value from the URL
    const prId = "12512" //We can make it dynamic
    const url = window.location.href;//window,location.href;
    const id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    const output = id.replace(/[a-zA-Z=]/g, '');

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello {value}</h1>
            <hr />
            <h2>{url} took from prId</h2>
            <hr />
            <h2><a className="redirect" href={'//www.check.com/prId/' + output} target="_blank">Click Here</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374257/error-window-not-defined-in-node-js seems like a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

The location is in the props, since window isn't defined in React.

Just do `this.props.location.pathname` instead of `window.location.href`.

More infos if you log the props.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
       at SampleApp (/Users/scrpatlolla/Desktop/Test/react-amp-template/examples/build/demo.js:41:24)
       at /Users/scrpatlolla/Desktop/Test/react-amp-template/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:306:16
       at measureLifeCyclePerf (/Users/scrpatlolla/Desktop/Test/react-amp-template/node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:75:12)

Comment: Please see the error. if I use this.props.location.pathname.

Comment: Please see the full file https://github.com/scrpatlolla/react-amp-template/blob/master/examples/src/demo.js

Comment: you have a pure component. the first parameter passed to a pure component is the props.

Comment: you have to extract the location similar to how you extract value: `const SampleApp = ({ value, location }) = { ... }`

Comment: My bad, read too fast and hadn't seen you had a pure component

Comment: @hunter can you please extend this.. sorry I am new to react  const SampleApp = ({ value, location }) = { ... }

Comment: const SampleApp = ({ value, location }) => {

    // --- CUSTOM-SCRIPTS ---
    addMeta([
        {type: 'meta', content: {content: 'something'}},
        {type: 'link', content: {rel: 'http://link'}},
    ]);

    //Append the value from the URL
    const prId = "12512" //We can make it dynamic
    const url = this.props.location.pathname; //window,location.href;
    const id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    const output = id.replace(/[a-zA-Z=]/g, '');

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
       at SampleApp (/Users/scrpatlolla/Desktop/Test/react-amp-template/examples/build/demo.js:44:24)

Comment: You have already extracted `location`, so `this.props.location` doesn't exist. Use `location.pathname` instead.

Comment: pathname is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Install this library
`npm install --save-dev --save-exact jsdom jsdom-global`
Then import it at the top of your component
`import 'jsdom-global/register';`
Hope it helps.